# json_encode with PHP 5.1.6 and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

PHP5.1.6 has no json_encode(), so I wanted to use function found on [json_encode documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#107968).
I am trying to use output of this function with ajax request:

```
fetchArticles: function( e ) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'article.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  { id: $(this).data( 'id_prod' ) },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( results ) {
          console.log('finished');
          console.log(results);
        }
      });
```

In `article.php` I have at this time:

```
if ( isset($_POST['id']) ) {
 connect();
 $articles = get_articles( $_POST['id'] );
 echo json_encode( $articles ); return;
}
```

The problem is with returning results to JS console:

- if there is no results, empty array is printed,
- if there is one results, proper object is printed,
- but when there is more than one result nothing is being printed to console, not even word `finished`.

I can see in HTTP headers and responses that proper data is returned, but it is not printed to console. Could you help me with solving this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a sample JSON that you are sending?

Comment: Here is HTTP response with more then one result: `[{"id_news":"38","img":"1313153502.jpg","no":"2","title":"Lorem ipsum"},{"id_news":"39","img":"1313153981.jpg","no":"2","title":"Ipsum lorem"}]`

Comment: Ooops, I wasn't precise enough. In title I have character `'` and it causes `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad escaped character`. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the json file can't be converted it throws `parsererror` exception, so try this:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'article.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data:  { id: $(this).data( 'id_prod' ) },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( results ) {
      console.log('finished');
      console.log(results);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
      console.debug(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); 
    }
  });
```

It will output your error when the JSON is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got following output: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad escaped character` and I checked that it is caused by `'` character. If I remove it from data everything works. How can I avoid this?

Comment: you can escape your `'` using `\` before it. Replace your data, now I don't remember the php function that done it, but json_encode was design to do it for your... but... good luck :)

Comment: I have replaced all quote characters with `&#39;` Thanks!